# Implementing automatic derivation without macros?

Tags: rust, traits, macro, typeclasses

In Rust:

```rust
#[derive(Display)]
struct Foo<T>(T);
```

If `T` conforms to the `Display` trait, then `Foo<T>` can automatically implement `Display` using a macro.

Is there an approach to accomplish this automatic implementation that doesn't rely on the macro system?

Comment: In C# attributes and reflection can be used to automatically implement behavior: `[DebuggerDisplay("x = {x} y = {y}")] class Foo`. It's not an interface though. [DebuggerDisplay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Either reflection (basically, resolve the structure and implementation at runtime instead of compile time), or structural type-level hackery like Haskell's GHC generics (https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics)

Comment: Or compile-time execution (comptime) like in Zig (https://kristoff.it/blog/what-is-zig-comptime/)

Answer (score 4):

#### Compile time source generation

That is, instead of using simple string concatenation (via a crude macro system) or trying to make the macro system [Turing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136686/is-the-c99-preprocessor-turing-complete) [complete](https://sdleffler.github.io/RustTypeSystemTuringComplete/) with a lot of extra syntax, you could use the very source language to do this.

Something like [C# source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview).

This is a extreme form of the [lexer hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexer_hack), where the compiler runs some previous compiled source generator at some specifics steps on parsing and/or compiling stages of normal code, so this source generators inject pure new code, or directly inspect and create/modify AST nodes in the intermediary compiled state.

```rust
#[sgen(Display)]   // Register a source generator for later execution.
struct Foo<T>(T);  // The "visible" source code, parsed from file.

// When the compiler finds the end of struct in visible source code,
// execute registered source generators, to inject new code or to
// modify the parsed AST. (after the only `;` in this example)
```

If the compiler is already [bootstrapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)), it's easier to implement source generators, as any internal compiler infrastructure can be exposed without code duplication.

Comment: Another example is Swift's [Sourcery](https://krzysztofzablocki.github.io/Sourcery/) and Kotlin's [KSP](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-overview.html).